# Getting some errors messages at boot

Tags: boot, radeon

Guys i've addded the picture of the messages of what i get during. Hope you people could figure out what is the reason for these messages. I am on ubuntu 15.10 64bit and on 4.2.5-040205-generic kernel. I think this has something to do with my GPU but not sure what.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Pm0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drm/radeon, adds pm sysfs files late. Added early in the driver init provess which means that in some cases driver was not finished initializing before other tools try to use it which could results in a crash report depending on bad timing.

I think this issue has been fixed in kernel 4.3